# How to manage multi Text Field validation in material-ui react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, material-ui

I am creating a form in Materia-UI and React.js, and I am making validation of two TextField. I want to validate both TextFields with same **error** and **textHelper** props. Below I have show a piece of code of my work. If somebody have an idea please share with me, it will be helpful.

```
const AddPost = ({error, helperText, handleInputChange, handleSubmit}) => {
  <div>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <TextField value={titleValue} onChange={handleInputChange} helperText={helperText} error={error} name={"title"} />
    <TextField value={bodyValue} onChange={handleInputChange} helperText={helperText} error={error} name={"body"} />
    </form>
  </div>
}


class Post extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
        this.state = {
          body: '',
          title: '',
          helperText: "",
          error: false,
    }
  }

  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    })
    if (event.target.value < 1) {
      this.setState({
        error: true,
        helperText: "This field is required!",
      })
   } else {
      this.setState({
        error: false,
        helperText: "",
      })
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
       <AddPost
          titleValue={this.state.title}
          bodyValue={this.state.body}
          handleInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
          handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          helperText={this.state.helperText}
          error={this.state.error}
       />
    )
  }
}
```

Helper text is shown in both of TextFields even if I write only in first. Please help me to solve this issue, you will save my day.

Answer (score 1):

It is a late answer but maybe it helps for others.

As I see your error message depends of your error state. That means that you can add if statement in `helperText`. So you only need to change error state to change `helperText` message:

```
class Post extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
        this.state = {
          body: '',
          title: '',
          helperText: "This field is required!",
          error: false,
    }
  }

  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    })
    if (event.target.value < 1) {
      this.setState({
        error: true
      })
   } else {
      this.setState({
        error: false
      })
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
       <AddPost
          titleValue={this.state.title}
          bodyValue={this.state.body}
          handleInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
          handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          helperText={this.state.error && this.state.helperText}
          error={this.state.error}
       />
    )
  }
}
```

As you can see I added in `helperText` if statement: if `this.state.error === true` then show `this.state.helperText` and if `this.state.error === false` then show nothing.